# Displaying integer-only values on the legend of a ggballoonplot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
my_data <- read.table(text = 

"Name  Make  Count
Rex  BMW  4
Uma  Mercedes  3
Mike  Mercedes  3
Carol  Mercedes  3
Carol BMW  3
Jason  Audi  2
Gary  Audi  2
Stephanie  Mercedes  2
Moses  Mercedes  2
Cary  Mercedes  2
Allen  Mercedes  2
Harry  Honda  2
Deg  Honda  2
Carol  Honda  2", header=TRUE)
```

I'm interested in generating a Balloon Plot to display the relative impact of User and Make.  The code I'm using to do so is as follows:

```
ggballoonplot(my_data, x='Make', y='Name', fill='Count', shape = 21, sorted=FALSE) +
  gradient_fill(c('green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'))
```

Checking the documentation at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.2.5/topics/ggballoonplot, I don't see any options that would prevent the legend from displaying non-integer values.

Is it possible to display integer-only values on the legend of a ggballoonplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ggballoonplot` is based on `ggplot2`, you can use `scale_fill_gradientn` and `scale_size` to set appropriate values and breaks to display only integer values:

```r
ggballoonplot(my_data, x='Make', y='Name', fill='Count', shape = 21, sorted=FALSE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours =  c('green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'), breaks = c(2,3,4))+
  scale_size(range = c(1,10), breaks =c(2,3,4))
```

[image]